# How to automate Cloud Watch Dashboards.?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I have several dashboards in CloudWatch that represent a view of my infrastructure: Number of instances from an autoscaling-group that are currently running, the CPU/Disk usage per instance, etc. However, when I update an autoscaling-group, I have to manually update the dashboards (autoscaling-group ID) to include its EC2 instances in the display. I'm looking for some kind of metric/dimension that can filter autoscaling-groups by tag. Is it possible, if yes then how? if no, how can I make it differently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build lambda function to do this job.

Configure lambda function to trigger every few minutes and check the autoscaling group for addition/removal of instances and update the cloudwatch dashboard accordingly

1 . Create a lambda function to check the instance present in the ASG and update the CW dashboard based on the instances present in the dashboard.

2 . Create a cloudwatch rule to trigger the lambda function every 5/10 minutes

Comment: Is there any documentation or guided tutorial about that that you know? I don't see how to update the CloudWatch Dashboard configuration with a lambda function.